# Data binding fails when changing numbers on numericUpDown

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, numericupdown

I have a databinding like this:

```
    numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", myBox1, "Width");
```

Whenever myBox1.Width changes it will update numericUpDown1.Value.

The problem is when entering new numbers on the control, myBox1.Width will not be updated immediately, but only after the cursor leaves the text area of the control. Is there any workaround to this bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the code like this:

```
numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", myBox1, "Width", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: There's no matching signature but numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", myBox1, "Width", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged) works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with the help of the previous answer, replacing false with true.
it works for me

```
numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", myBox1, "Width", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```